# Numpad Enter key in i3

Tags: i3

My i3 config depends heavily on Enter key and I couldn't find to get the Numpad's Enter key to working.
Left Enter key works just fine but the whole problem is with Right Enter/Numpad's Enter key. Any help is highly appreciated.

My i3 version is 4.22. Numlock is activated by the way.

Comment: Is NumLock activated?

Comment: Does deactivating NumLock affects Enter functions? Hmm.

Comment: Deactivating NumLock doesn't affect the Right Enter functions for me.